# Get ServerRelativeUrl property on SharePoint page using JavaScript without loading SP.JS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

1. I want to get `ServerRelativeUrl` property on SharePoint page using JavaScript without loading SP.JS file. Is there any way to get this.

E.g. URL: https://example.domain.com/sites/sample/pages/home.aspx
I want "/sites/sample" as my Server Relative Url

2. If above does not works then can I get Server Relative Url using only JavaScript code i.e. without using SharePoint refrence, something like `window.location`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please refer this link from TechNet. This will work for you - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29766.sharepoint-understanding-the-sppagecontextinfo-object.aspx

Comment: You can inspect the debug versions of SP.JS and recreate the object yourself, but I really have to wonder why you can't just use SP.JS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl` to get the server relative url as same as '/sites/sample'

Answer (score 0):

I can use `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` to get server relative url of current web or `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl` to get that or current site.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Gert, use the below JavaScript snippet to get the server relative URL

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var serverRelativeUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
    alert(serverRelativeUrl);
    </script>
```